# Checking if a set of vector Spans & linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have this so easy question, yet it is giving me a headache.

> Consider the following two subsets of $\mathbb R^3$:
> \begin{align}
> S_2 &= \{(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9), (10,11,12)\}, \\
> S_3 &= \{(1,0,-1), (1,0,1)\}.
> \end{align}
> Which of the sets $S_i$ span $\mathbb R^3$ and which of the sets $S_i$ are linearly independent?

Here’s what I know for sure:

$S_3$ does not span $\mathbb R^3$ since it has only 2 vectors and $2 < 3 = \dim \mathbb R^3$.

$S_3$ is linearly independent since neither of the two vectors in $S_3$ is a multiple of each other.

$S_2$ is not linearly independent since $S_2$ has 4 vectors and $4 > 3 = \dim \mathbb R^3$.

Here’s what I’m not quite sure about:

Does $S_2$ span $\mathbb R^3$? I know it doesn’t if its dimension, call it $n$, is smaller than $\mathbb R^n$ but what if there are more vectors?

Comment: There’s no special trick that lets you look at a set of $k$ vectors in $R^3$ and determine the dimension of its span. One way to proceed is to form the $3\times k$ matrix with your vectors as its columns, then compute the rank of this matrix by putting it into row-echelon form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re correct, dimension arguments can be useful. When they’re not enough, go back to the definitions. To say that $S_2$ spans $\mathbb{R}^3$ means that any vector $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ can be written as a linear combination $a_1(1,2,3) + a_2(4,5,6) + a_3(7,8,9) + a_4(10,11,12) = (a,b,c)$ for some scalars $a_1,\ldots,a_4$. This is just a linear system, and the question amounts to asking whether this system possesses a solution.

Comment: if this was a square matrix, all i need to find is its determinant but since its 3x4 i guess i have to do row echelon form to see if it has a solution right?

Comment: @Allie Yes, that is one way to solve the problem.

Comment: if this matrix has an infinite number of solutions, does that mean it doesnt span?

Comment: @Allie For it to span, it must have at least one solution for *every* vector $(a,b,c)$. However, are you sure the system has a solution for, say, $(a,b,c) = (1,0,0)$?

Answer (score 2):

All your vectors in $S_2$ are of the form $(1,2,3) + i\ (3,3,3)$ for $i = 0,1,2,3$.  Thus $(1,2,3)$ and the single vector $(3,3,3)$ can generate all your set, and thus form all linear combinations of your set.  Hence the intrinsic dimensionality is $2$ (not $3$).

Answer (score 1):

A set of vectors can be infinite and *still* not span $\Bbb R^n.$ For example, consider the set of all vectors in $\Bbb R^2$ of the form $(x,0)$.

In order to determine whether $S_2$ spans $\Bbb R^3$, you should determine the span of $S_2$, or try to find three linearly-independent vectors in $S_2$.

Answer (score 1):

You have correctly deduced that $S_2$ consists on dependent vectors. That means that one of those vectors, let’s say $v_4$, can be expressed as a lineal combination of $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$. In that case, the space that $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\}$ spans is the same as the space that $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ does. You can see that every vector in the former space can be expressed as combination of the four vectors, and therefore the first three vectors are enough.

Now you only have to see whether $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ spans $\mathbb{R}^3$ or not. You can repeat the argument if you need it in a general case.